# Access the object calling a member function, within the function

Tags: c++, function, class, object

So i'm making a snowboarding game with SDL, and I have a function in the obstacle class that checks for collision. When the obstacle calls this function, if the player collided with it I went to set the collidedObject of the player class to the object it collided with. The code looks like this:

```
void Obstacle::checkCollision()
{
    // Check for collision
    // If player collided
    player.collidedObject = theObjectThatCalledThisFunction;
}
```

But i don't know how to get the object that called the function. Any help? I didn't really know what to search, and what i did try searching wasn't much help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` points to the object calling the member function. Hence, if `player.collidedObject` is of type `Obstacle`, then you could write

```
player.collidedObject = *this;
```

Comment: I think he is talking about the function that called checkCollision. Not necessarily the object itself.

Comment: Ahh I was just missing the * next to the this keyword. Coming from c#, I'm still getting used to the whole memory/pointers aspect of c++. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but it would make more sense for you to checkCollision somewhere outside the obstacle class. Something like:

```
bool Obstacle::checkCollision(Player &player) {
    //collision test here
    return collisionResult;
}

PlayerSystem::collisionTest() {
    foreach(Obstacle : ObstaclesCloseBy) {
        if(obstacle->checkCollision(player)
            player.rollLikeABarrelDownTheSlope(); //or whatever    
    }    
}
```